# SharePoint 2013 - Determine what search pages get placed higher than others

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013 search results tool, what are some things I can do to help bring curtain pages higher in the search than others.  For example if I search for help, and I have 10 help pages in my system that talk about help support for various things, I would like some help pages to display 1st, 2nd, while other help pages can load in the results later.

What are something things I can do?

Answer (score 0):

This used to be accomplished via keyword configuration within the search center. In 2013 this has changed to [Query Rules](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2012/09/18/what-happened-to-best-bets-introducing-query-rules.aspx). Admittedly, I don't have much experience with this yet. Hopefully the MSDN blog post will get you started until some more answers flow in.